# How to implement calendar date picker instead of default date picker in Xamarin.ios

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

In my xamarin.ios app(not xamarin forms) I need to replace a default date picker by any date picker which allows to pick date from calendar. I searched a lot but could not find any suitable easy solution. I am not sure is it even possible or not to achieve in xamarin.ios. If you know any way to achieve this please let me know. Thanks

Comment: What exact effect do you want to achieve ? Can you provide an image to demonstrate ?

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT there is a label. When some one tap on that label I want a calendar date picker should pop up. Then after tapping on a date from the calendar it will dismiss and the selected date will be the value of the label Text. That's it. Please help me sir

Comment: Create a button , pop up the calendar date picker  when click on the button , and show the selected date on the button when dismiss calendar  .

Comment: Label or button is not the main problem sir. The main problem is I don't know how to implement a calendar date picker as they only provide a default UIDatePicker which doesn't come with anything like a calendar. I hope you can understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: Check the link for calendar plugin : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/61145/how-can-i-generate-a-calendar-in-xamarins-forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Ios 14 and above we get new UIDatePicker which comes with different style options like compact, inline which shows a calendar modal to pick date from.